# Better function to find the next instance of a sub-buffer within a buffer when you know the minimum distance to look?

Tags: node.js, csv, buffer

**Summary:**

I'm aware there are CSV file reading libraries for Node.js. I wanted to make my own function to implement the most optimization possible based on the shortcuts I can take knowing the properties of my specific CSV format.

I'm working with a variable entry-count-per line file, so I can't simply scrape the buffer for a specified number of comma matches and load my field data with the correct buffers, I need to find the end of the line first. **So this code is strictly aiming to go line by line through the file buffer by finding the next `\n` as efficiently as possible.**

**Problem:**

`binaryUtils.findBuffer` is the issue in this code.

**Question:**

Is there a way to write `binaryUtils.findBuffer` more efficiently? Is it optimal for the given scenario?

**Code:**

I load the file into a buffer (or at least as large of a chunk of it as is possible):

```
// I know that the minimum length of a line in this CSV
// so I can skip ahead to find the exact location of the 
// newline without testing every character pair for the 
// end of the line:
const minOffset = 208 // minimum byte length of a line
const maxReadChunk = 2147483647
const csvPath = sourceFolderPath + "/" + processQueue[index]
console.log("loading source data path:", csvPath)
const fd = fs.openSync(csvPath, "r+")
const stats = fs.statSync(csvPath)

let optionCount = 0
let fileSize = stats["size"]
let totalFileSize = fileSize
let chunk = 0;
const chunks = Math.ceil(fileSize / maxReadChunk)
let bufferSize = Math.min(maxReadChunk, fileSize)
let readOffset = bufferSize
fileSize -= bufferSize
let fileBuffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(bufferSize)
fs.readSync(fd, fileBuffer, 0, bufferSize, 0)
```

Then I loop through line by line, and benchmark along the way

```
let linePointer = 0
let nextLinePointer
let line
let findStart
let findEnd
let findDuration
let findTotal = 0
let loadStart = moment()
while (true) {
  // `performance` imported from require('perf_hooks') to get fractions
  // of milliseconds whereas moment() only captures nearest ms
  findStart = performance.now() 
  // the logs that I show from the benchmarking on binaryUtils.findBuffer
  // will demonstrates, as expected, that it is taking up 97%+ of the
  // processing time. See below for binaryUtils.findBuffer code
  nextLinePointer = binaryUtils.findBuffer(
      newLineBuffer, 
      newLineBufferSize, 
      fileBuffer, 
      bufferSize, 
      linePointer, 
      minOffset
  )
  findEnd = performance.now()
  findDuration = findEnd - findStart
  findTotal += findDuration
  // console.log("found nextLinePointer", nextLinePointer)
  if (nextLinePointer === false) {
    if (chunk < chunks) {
      chunk++
      console.log("progressed to chunk", chunk, "/", chunks)
      bufferSize = Math.min(maxReadChunk, fileSize)
      fileBuffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(bufferSize)
      fs.readSync(fd, fileBuffer, 0, bufferSize, readOffset)
      readOffset += bufferSize
    } else {
      console.log("reached end of file")
      break
    }
  } else {
    optionCount++
    if (optionCount % 5000 === 0) {
      line = fileBuffer.slice(linePointer + 1, nextLinePointer)
      let now = moment();
      duration = now - loadStart;
      let rate = optionCount / duration;
      let timeDiff = now.diff(loadStart)
      console.clear()
      console.log("found line:", binaryUtils.readStr(line))
      console.log("Initializing option chains at rate of", 
          rate.toFixed(2), "items / ms")
      console.log("Chunk: \t", chunk + 1, "/", chunks)
      console.log("Start time: \t", loadStart.format("HH:m:ss"))
      console.log("Current time: \t", now.format("HH:m:ss"))
      console.log("Duration: \t", moment.utc(timeDiff).format("HH:mm:ss"))
      console.log("Processed: \t", nextLinePointer, "/", totalFileSize, 
          "bytes, (", ((nextLinePointer / totalFileSize) * 100).toFixed(2), "% )")
      console.log("Finding line has taken:", 
          moment.utc(findTotal).format("HH:mm:ss"), "/", 
          moment.utc(timeDiff).format("HH:mm:ss"), "total duration (", 
          ((findTotal / timeDiff) * 100).toFixed(2), "% )")
    }
    linePointer = nextLinePointer
  }
}
```

And the culprit of the theoretically slow (35 line / ms) processing of this buffer is:

```
binaryUtils.findBuffer = (
    targetBuffer, 
    targetBufferSize, 
    sourceBuffer, 
    sourceBufferSize, 
    pointer, 
    minOffset
) => {
  pointer += minOffset
  while (true) {
    newPointer = pointer + targetBufferSize
    if (newPointer > sourceBufferSize) return false
    slice = sourceBuffer.slice(newPointer, newPointer + targetBufferSize)
    if (slice.equals(targetBuffer)) {
      return newPointer
    }
    pointer = newPointer
  }
}
```

And here's the console output:

```
found line: FHR,2004-01-21 16:00:00,FHR,2004-02-21,30.000,P,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0,20,2.7000,20,3.1000,27.2300,27.2500,1,9,20,2.7000,20,3.1000
Initializing option chains at rate of 87.33 items / ms
Chunk:   1 / 2
Start time:      08:47:40
Current time:    08:54:13
Duration:        00:06:33
Processed:       2147152582 / 3461193224 bytes, ( 62.04 % )
Finding line has taken: 00:06:25 / 00:06:33 total duration ( 97.90 % )
```

The processing rate is obviously not really useful for categorizing the operation as slow without knowing system specs and comparison benchmarks, but my question is about whether or not the fundamental design of `binaryUtils.findBuffer` is optimal.

A secondary benchmark just to make sure slicing buffers from a large buffer isn't slow for some reason:

```
let fileBuffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(bufferSize)
fs.readSync(fd, fileBuffer, 0, bufferSize, 0)
let sliceCount = 100000
let sliceStart = performance.now()
  for (let i = 0; i < sliceCount; i++) {
  let newBuffer = fileBuffer.slice(i, i + 300)
}
let sliceEnd = performance.now()
let duration = sliceEnd - sliceStart
let rate = sliceCount / duration
console.log(sliceCount, "slices in", duration, "ms for rate of", rate, "/ ms")
```

output:

```
100000 slices in 7.09850001335144 ms for rate of 14087.483244616722 / ms
```

Comment: Edited the code, at first I had a bug where I wasnt actually leveraging the minimum offset. fixed, which tripled performance, but it should still be way faster

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I keep making the mistake of forgetting just how much faster low level operations are than anything we can do manually with JS...

`indexOf` written in C is just so much faster than using a loop to search the buffer, that was the solution.

```
let start
const findBuffer = (
    targetBuffer, 
    targetBufferSize, 
    sourceBuffer, 
    sourceBufferSize, 
    pointer, 
    minOffset
) => {
    start = pointer + minOffset
    return start + sourceBuffer.slice(start, sourceBufferSize).indexOf(targetBuffer)
}
```

<s>750% faster, for a rate of 600 lines / ms</s>
2500% faster, for a rate of 2400 lines / ms if you remove the variable declaration within the function and reuse `start` defined with `let` outside the function